# While trying to deploy application in Weblogic 12c. i got exception

Tags: spring-mvc, cxf, weblogic12c

while deploy application in weblogic12c. i got following exception. i'm newbie to weblogic12c. any suggestion??

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.getBeanInfo(java.lang.Class)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.getBeanInfo(java.lang.Class)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.getBeanInfo(JAXBUtils.java:1155)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBSchemaInitializer.getBeanInfo(JAXBSchemaInitializer.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.checkForJAXBAnnotations(JAXBDataBinding.java:436)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.justCheckForJAXBAnnotations(JAXBDataBinding.java:424)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:349)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:446)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:453)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:536)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Comment: Can you brief the way you use to deploy. I mean the steps you used

Comment: Sounds like a "classpath hell" problem. Verify that you don't have several versions of JAXB library on your classpath.

Comment: I'm using weblogic12c to deploy. all servers started. while install war. i got above mention exception. I'm using following jars,
cxf-2.6.9
cxf-manifest
cxf-xjc-boolean-2.6.2
cxf-xjc-dv-2.6.2
cxf-xjc-ts-2.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all jars with Java 8 specific. now it's working fine. Thanks for your support guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting weblogic using admin console add the jar file details in server startup --> classpath or you are using script add the jar details in setDomainenv.sh file then try to deploy the war file.